# How is it possible to make one component stand out from other same component in React

Tags: reactjs

I was creating React project and I have  component which is used in several places in the project. The question is how is it possible to make one certain  different from other instances of that component in terms of css styling?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving that you have to accept the styles of the component as props. And each time you use the component pass the desired style to each instance.

For example

```
const PopupHeader = ({ title, onClose, classes }) => (
  <div className={classNames(styles.head, classes.header)}>
    <span className={styles.headText}>
      {title}
    </span>
  </div>
);
```

Here the `PopupHeader` component is receiving classes as props which is actually an object of styles passed from parent component, which is used in the child component.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contextAPI` for sending the styles in all components

```
<ParentComponent>
   <Style.Provider value={{ style: "background: "white .. or something" }}>
      {this.props.children}
   </Style.Provider>
</ParentComponent>
```

You can send the styles in all child components